# Capacitor Android not loading http javascript source

Tags: javascript, android, http, https, capacitor

Im trying to load remote scripts / css from my local web server under url of http://127.0.0.1:4002/

But seem to be having error in capacitor android, capacitor ios is working fine.
I also manage to load the css from without any error
https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap-grid.min.css

My guess is not supporting http?

Here is my code in loading it

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap-grid.min.css" />
        <link href="http://127.0.0.1:4002/test/fonts.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta
            name="viewport"
            content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, width=device-width, height=device-height, viewport-fit=cover,  user-scalable=no"
        />
        <title>My Title</title>
    </head>

    <body id="body">
        
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is the error i got under 'chrome://inspect/#devices'
[image]

My dependencies:

```
"@capacitor-community/http": "^1.0.0-alpha.1",
"@capacitor/android": "^3.0.0-rc.0",
"@capacitor/cli": "^3.0.0-rc.0",
"@capacitor/core": "^3.0.0-rc.0",
"@capacitor/device": "^0.5.5",
"@capacitor/dialog": "^0.4.5",
"@capacitor/filesystem": "^0.5.1",
"@capacitor/ios": "^3.0.0-rc.0",
```

My capacitor.config.json

```
{
    "appId": "com.example.app",
    "appName": "hello-cap-2",
    "bundledWebRuntime": false,
    "npmClient": "npm",
    "webDir": "www",
    "plugins": {
        "SplashScreen": {
            "launchShowDuration": 0
        }
    },
    "server": {
        "allowNavigation": ["*"]
    },
    "android": {
        "allowMixedContent": true
    },
    "cordova": {}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the answer at
https://github.com/ionic-team/capacitor/discussions/4477

> 127.0.0.1 is your computer, iOS simulator understand it because the simulator is running on your computer, but on Android, the emulator is
> a "virtual machine" with its own networking, so 127.0.0.1 for it its
> the own emulator, not your computer.
>
> You can enable port forwarding to send the 4002 port traffic to the
> emulator, or you can use 10.0.2.2 IP as it automatically loops to
> 127.0.0.1
>
> https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-networking
>
> Also, note that using 127.0.0.1 won't work on real devices because of
> the same reason, it's better if you use the local IP of the computer
> instead, something like 192.168.1.30